# Load dynamically bundles - Symfony 5

Tags: php, symfony, bundle, symfony5

As you should know, in /src, you've a file called Kernel.php which has a function called registerBundles. It loads all bundle listed in the file bundles.php from config folder. Instead of loading manually each bundle, i would like to do it more dynamically.
I'm currently facing the following problem : I don't know how to resolve class name without the attribute ::class.
Indeed, when you take a look at bundles.php, you've this array :

```
<?php

return [
  Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle::class => ['all' => true],
  Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle::class => ['all' => true],
  Twig\Extra\TwigExtraBundle\TwigExtraBundle::class => ['all' => true],
  Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle::class => ['all' => true],
  Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle::class => ['all' => true],
  Doctrine\Bundle\MigrationsBundle\DoctrineMigrationsBundle::class => ['all' => true],
  Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle::class => ['all' => true],
  Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle::class => ['dev' => true, 'test' => true],
  Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle::class => ['all' => true],
  Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle::class => ['dev' => true, 'test' => true],
  Symfony\Bundle\MakerBundle\MakerBundle::class => ['dev' => true],
];
```

In my database, i've got the namespace of bundles i want to load dynamically but i don't know how to inject them in this array with the correct ::class class name resolver.
Do you have any suggestion ?

Comment: some bundles have a fundamental impact on how symfony works. some pages in your project may not work at all if some bundles are not loaded, some things are *cached* and on disabling bundles "dynamically" won't change until the cache is rebuilt, some stuff will just crash until the cache is rebuilt. This is due to bundles providing CompilerPasses (essentially: stuff symfony should do in the caching phase). you need consistency ... a cache is somewhat tied to the set of loaded bundles, be aware of that

Comment: Have you checked what "class name plus ::class" is? That's some kind of magic string, there's no technical need to write it that way.

Comment: @NicoHaase there's a code style reason though. If you put it in quotes, you may have a typo Hower, this way the class has to exist and be loadable, which even static code analysis can pick up. without `::class` it's a syntax error, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: All the ::class does is to turn the class name into a string so it becomes suitable for use as an array key.  And at the same time provides a bit of verification that the bundle is actually installed.  All the OP needs to do is to use the actually fully qualified class name without the ::class suffix.  Of course, many bundles require application level configuration so that will be more challenging to control dynamically.  And changing the bundles means updating your cache so this is not something done on a per request basis.

Comment: @Jakumi yeah you're right, that's the problem i already faced.

Comment: @craigh I've take a look to what you did but i don't perfectly understand how you proceed.

Comment: Moreover, how to manage the problem of the configuration ? When not loaded, it will display an error due to the fact that no one load this configuration.

Comment: all of our dynamic bundles require no config.

Comment: Well, if every time a user want to install the bundle I automatically create the config file, will it work ?

Comment: @Jakumi I know about that special function of `::class` in terms of refactoring, but having a dynamically loaded string from the database containing the name of a bundle destroys this possibility anyways

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?  I need to know how to register a bundle in the bundles.php file from another bundle as a dependency;  I thought using PrependExtensionInterface as mentioned on this page would be the solution but I cannot find exactly how to do this anywhere:  https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/prepend_extension.html#more-than-one-bundle-using-prependextensioninterface